# visualize timeseries data that changes in small intervals with javascript / jqplot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I try to visualize some data, that changes in very short intervals from second to second, with a simple line chart in a browser with javascript (testData).

I have tried it with jqplot, see code above. The problem is that it seems that the interval between the times is too small for jqplot...the browser crashes every time when i try to create the graph.

Any ideas? A nice zoom function like this would also be nice:

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/rotatedTickLabelsZoom.html

1.) Is there a way to do this with jqplot? What do i wrong?

Update: See better fiddle here: http://jsbin.com/onufih/9/

html:

```
        <div id="overviewChart"></div>
```

Here's my js-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// testData that works fine:

var testData = [['2008-10-29 10:00:00', 0], ['2008-10-30 10:00:10', 1]]; 

// testData that works not fine, time intervals are too small: 

var testData = [['2008-10-29 10:00:00', 0], ['2008-10-29 10:00:10', 1],
                ['2008-10-29 10:00:11', 0], ['2008-10-29 10:00:14', 1]];

var overviewChart = $.jqplot('overviewChart', [testData], {
    title : 'Rotated Axis Text',
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            tickOptions : {

                formatString : '%#m/%#d/%y - %#H h - %#M m - %#S s',
                fontSize : '10pt',
                fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
                angle : -40
            }
        },
        yaxis : {
            rendererOptions : {
                tickRenderer : $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            },
            tickOptions : {
                fontSize : '10pt',
                fontFamily : 'Tahoma',
                angle : 30
            }
        }
    },
    series : [{
        lineWidth : 4,
        markerOptions : {
            style : 'square'
        }
    }],
    cursor : {
        zoom : true,
        looseZoom : true
    }
});

});
```

Comment: please create a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/ with your code

Comment: Fiddle is online now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please load all the required js files for rendering axis

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT :

There is some exception or infinite loop is coming in the automatic calculation of ticks for the chart. What you can do is write a function to calculate the tick points and give it for `ticks` property in axis options. An example function is given below which will select all the points in the data as tick points.

```
function getTicks() {

    var ticks = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var item = data[i];
        var dateStr = item[0];
        ticks.push(dateStr);
    }

    return ticks;
}

...

xaxis: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
    },
    ticks: getTicks(), // use the function to get the array of tick points
    tickOptions: {

        formatString: '%#m/%#d/%y - %#H h - %#M m - %#S s',
        fontSize: '10pt',
        fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
        angle: -40
    }
}
...
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/onufih/6/edit

You can modify this function in such a way that it will return an array of equidistant points between first time stamp and the last.

Comment: Hi, nice try! But when i add more data, the problem remains the same, see here: http://jsbin.com/onufih/9/

Comment: sometime is not working as the js files are not getting loaded.. otherwise it is working for me...

Comment: Yeah, but the zoom function doesn't work...but you get the points ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Pondjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pondjs) or [Momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) to do this, it also has the zoom feature and it is much cleaner, but can be a little tedious. It deals with these points and auto plots them based on how to create the code based on chart implementation chart by using react-timeseries-charts. They both work well together with pond or moment.